# Se envia el boton pulsado con ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tengo un formulario con 2 botones en el que dependiendo del botón pulsado registra o edita, el problema es que no consigo detectar cual de los dos botones he pulsado, aquí el código:

HTML

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" name='registroforoedit' id="registroforoedit" onsubmit="finRegistroEdit(); return false">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" id="nuevo" name="nuevo" value="nuevo">Nueva version</button>
        <button type="submit" id="editar" name="editar" value="editar">Editar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```js
function finRegistroEdit(){
    var dataString = $('#registroforoedit').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/ed_presupuestos_back.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("registroforoedit").reset();
        }
    });
}
```

ed_presupuestos_back.php

```php
    $nuevo=$_POST["nuevo"];//no recibo ningún valor
    $editar=$_POST["editar"];//no recibo ningún valor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que en jQuery, el método `serialize()` no recoge los botones o input de tipo submit, porque dicho método no tiene medio para saber cuál botón, entre varios posibles, ha sido presionado.

Esto viene explicado claramente en la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/#serialize):

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
> submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
> using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
> serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
> checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
> are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
> is not serialized.

---

> Nota: Solo los "controles correctos" se serializan en la cadena. No se
> serializa ningún valor de botón de envío ya que el formulario no se
> envió mediante un botón. Para que el valor de un elemento de
> formulario se incluya en la cadena serializada, el elemento debe tener
> un atributo de name. Los valores de las casillas de verificación y los
> botones de opción (entradas de tipo "radio" o "casilla de
> verificación") se incluyen solo si están marcadas. Los datos de los
> elementos de selección de archivos no se serializan.

Para este caso concreto, si lo que quieres es saber cuál de los botones fue pulsado, puedes escuchar los clicks de ambos botones y luego usar `this` para saber cuál de ellos fue pulsado, poniendo en una clave (aquí la he llamado `action`), el valor del botón. Así en el servidor sabrás qué *acción* ejecutar.

Si el formulario tuviera más datos que quieras pasar, puedes usar `serialize()` con el id del formulario para incluir dichos datos en la variable `toPost` y postearla vía Ajax.

### JS

```js
$( "#nuevo,#editar" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
   var toPost={ action : $( this ).val()};
   console.log( toPost );

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/ed_presupuestos_back.php",
        data: toPost,
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("registroforoedit").reset();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" name='registroforoedit' id="registroforoedit" onsubmit="finRegistroEdit(); return false">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" id="nuevo" name="nuevo" value="nuevo">Nueva version</button>
        <button type="submit" id="editar" name="editar" value="editar">Editar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

### PHP

```
$mAction=!empty($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : NULL;

if($mAction) {
    #En caso de más de dos acciones podría pensarse en algo más simple
    #como un bloque switch u otro
    if ($mAction==='editar') {
        #Código para editar
    } else {
        #Código para nuevo
    }
} else {
    #Ningún action fue enviado
}
```

### Recomendaciones

1. No declares tu formulario como `enctype="multipart/form-data"` si no lo es. En este formulario no se aprecia que estés pasando archivos por ejemplo para declarar que es multipart.
2. Es una mala práctica usar funciones in-line, como ocurre aquí: `onsubmit="finRegistroEdit(); return false"` Esto hace que el contenido HTML sea siempre dependiente del código Javascript. Si mañana esa función debe cambiar de nombre, recibir parámetros, etc, y la tienes *in line* en cientos o miles de archivos HTML te quiero ver adivinando en qué archivos la has puesto. Considera por tanto escuchar los envíos de formularios, clicks, cambios de elementos, etc directamente en Javascript (como se ha hecho en esta respuesta). Si observas aquí el código JS no depende para nada del HTML. Al bloque `$( "#nuevo,#editar" ).on( "click", function( e ) {` puedes agregar lo que quieras sin tocar para nada el contenido HTML.

Comment: De acuerdo gracias por la respuesta, pero si el ajax lo tengo en otro archivo? presupuesto.js, he cogido la aplicación casi terminada y no me dan tiempo a arreglar los muchos errores que tiene como los que mencionaste arriba

Comment: @Superchicken puedes corregir el código en ese archivo .js que refieres